# Ignite 2.0 how to swap to hard disk

Tags: ignite

When I do some test with ignite memory, some problems come to me.
The document said I can set the swap to hard disk enable in cacheconfiguration and set the swap file path in MemoryPolicyConfiguration.
However, the swapenable is missing in ignite 2.0 and setswapfile still exists. So, I wonder whether is swapping to disk still available in ignite 2.0. If so, how can I manage it.

Answer (score 3):

define your memory policy, then inject into your cache. like this:

```
            <!-- Defining a custom memory policy. -->
            <property name="memoryPolicies">
                <list>

                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.MemoryPolicyConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                        <!-- 100 MB memory region with disabled eviction -->
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{100 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <!-- Setting a name of the swapping file. -->
                        <property name="swapFilePath" value="mindMemoryPolicySwap"/>                           
                    </bean>
```

try it.

Comment: I'm sorry ,It doesn't work. I set the memoryPolicies but the swap didn't happen. Before ignite 2.0, we should  set both the  swapenable and memoryPolicies but in ignite 2.0 we can only set the memoryPolicies, but it doesn't work. Did I miss some operation?